# How to pass metadata for stripe payments in ColdFusion cfpayment library?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm using the ColdFusion [CFPayment Library](https://github.com/ghidinelli/cfpayment) for processing Stripe payments. The payments are working fine, but now I want to pass metadata values to along with the transaction.

I went into the [stripe.cfc](https://github.com/ghidinelli/cfpayment/blob/master/api/gateway/stripe/stripe.cfc) file in the library and passed the static metadata values, but in the stripe logs it's showing a request like this:

```
{
  "firstname2": "test",
  "source": "tok_1**************",
  "currency": "usd",
  "description": "test",
  "amount": "3300"
}
```

The value **firstname2** was supposed to be in metadata, but it's automatically putting this value in the main array / json.

**Added later**

```
TransactionData = {
    "description" = "test",
    "metadata[test]" = "1",
    "metadata[FirstName]" = "Abdur",
    "metadata[LastName]" = "Rehman",
    "description" = "Online Donation"
 };

gw_response = gw.purchase(money=money, account=account, options=TransactionData);
```

I modified my code according to your example but TransactionData items are not being displayed in the request.

Comment: Please include the code that you modified to add the metadata.

Answer (score 2):

I've been successfully using metadata w/Stripe using CFPayment.  When authorizing, you need to pass an object as the third parameter and name your keys something like this.:

```
TransactionData = {
  "statement_descriptor" = "Descriptor Override (5-22 chars)",
  "metadata[test]" = "1",
  "metadata[donorid]" = DonorID,
  "metadata[accountid]" = AccountID,
  "description" = "Online Donation"
};

authResponse = gateway.authorize(money, cardAccount, TransactionData);
```

"description" and "statement-descriptor" are not required, but I like to include them so I can override the Stripe account defaults.

Comment: Oh, got my mistake. I am trying to pass the parameters while charging the account. It should be passed when generating the token right?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pass the metadata in the purchase call of CFPayment library. The purchase function in stipe.cfc file was only passing pre-defined values to the payment gateway. I added the following code in the purchase function and it worked.

```
<cfloop collection="#arguments.options.metadata#" item="option_index">
      <cfset p["metadata[#option_index#]"] = #arguments.options.metadata[option_index]# />
</cfloop>
```

And passed the values to purchase function using the following code;

```
options["metadata"]["First Name"] = "Abdur";
options["metadata"]["Last Name"] = "Rehman";
gw_response = gw.purchase(money=money, account=account, options=options);
```